# How do I disregard bootstrap class on condition with angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, responsive-design

Context: We are trying to build a layout builder app, and want to see how the grid looks on tablet/mobile/desktop views.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-5 col-md-7 black"></div>
```

For example, if I have this kind of div, and the class kick in depending on the view size. So if I am on a desktop, what can I do to disregard lg class, and show sm class when I choose mobile or vice versa?

PS: I have searched around stackoverflow, and couldn't find the answer.

Edit: Common answers: Simple answer is yes, resize your browser, but I don't want the user to do it, I as a dev know about this, but a non technical person will not know about this, he/she would click on mobile/tablet Icon to view their page.

Comment: You resize your browser?

Comment: No idea what you mean by *"disregard"* or what the specific problem is. The media queries should take care of window size. If you have a problem provide a [mcve] that reproduces it

Comment: Use `ngClass`. It will fulfill your needs

Comment: He wants to view the page *"as mobile"* on a desktop. While Chrome does allow you to emulate a mobile device and request mobile website from desktop and viceversa, responsiveness in Bootstrap is implemented strictly on viewport size in pixels. So simply resizing your browser window will let you observe each case, depending on current browser width.

Comment: Why not just load the app in an iframe of that size?

Comment: Yup...emulate in iframe and toggle it's dimensions

Comment: Iframe, will kill the drag and drop functionality.

Comment: Split the screen, drag/drop on one side and emulator on the other

Comment: An alternative would be custom build boostrap css with additional prefix classes that can be toggled on your UI container

Comment: @Aijaz. If you want your website to be fully responsive works on desktop and mobile and you do not have any other options, my advice is to use <div (window:resize)="onResize($event)">. I use this throughout my application. See my profile and see the actual app. I hope you find your answers and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

try this

*TS*

```
export class AppComonent implements OnInit {
  wWidth: number;
  wHeight: number;

  constructor(){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    const ele = document.querySelector('.lorem') as HTMLElement;
    ele.addEventListener('click', (e: Event) => {
      this.wWidth = (<HTMLElement>e.target).clientWidth;
      this.wHeight = (<HTMLElement>e.target).clientHeight; // for ex purposes
    });
  }
}
```

use the native accessing selector in javascript to access to the element.

*HTML*

```
<div [ngClass]="{'col-sm-3': wWidth <= 575, 'col-md-7': (wWidth > 575) && (wWidth <= 992), 'col-lg-5': wWidth > 992  }"></div>
```

edit the *expression* as your needs that just the concept how to implement that.